# Running python script using Outlook VBA

Tags: python, vba, outlook, shellexecute

Im trying to run a python script using Outlook Vba. When I run the below code. A python icon appears in the taskbar for a second and disappears. When in fact it should open a dialogue box and prompt me to enter folder name. After which it should run the rest of the script as usual.

Please help me run this script from outlook as I regularly do by double clicking the .py file.

```
Sub runpythonscript()

Dim Path As String

Path = "python C:\Doc Management\Exstream_Reconciliation.py"

Shell(Path)

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok this is the solution for anyone looking

```
Sub RunPyFileFromMacroViaCmd()
    Dim Path As String
    Dim filepath As String
    filepath = """C:\Doc Management\Exstream_Reconciliation.py"""
    Path = "cmd /k" & filepath
    Shell (Path)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

VBA (nor Outlook) doesn't provide anything for debugging such cases. The best what you could do is to add log statements to the python script where you could output everything what happens in the code. Analyzing log files you will be able to figure the cause of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You have a space in the file name. It must be quoted.

Comment: I tried that as well. It doesn't work.

Comment: What is your latest code? Does it work if run the exact same command from a command prompt?

Comment: It runs when I use - start filename.py. Do you know the code to run this file in command prompt from outlook

Comment: Im able to open cmd from outlook as well. But Im unaware of how to give commands to change dir and start this .py file from outlook. Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: Does the following run from the command prompt `python "C:\Doc Management\Exstream_Reconciliation.py"`

Comment: Ok the tool ran and prompted me to enter folder name. When I did it gave error instead of running like usual. It said "The system cannot find the path specified. Please make sure the folder setup is correct." And a bunch of other stuff.

Comment: I tried changing the directory to where the path is, but it still gave me the same error.

Comment: Did that error come from Windows or from your script?

Comment: Ok I think that was from my script. I think I did not have my folder in the path.

Comment: I ran your query again. Its working fine. Please lmk if you know how to initiate this from outlook.

Comment: So what is different in Outlook?

Comment: Its not running from Outlook. It is showing a python icon in task bar and disappearing after a second when I run the code.

Comment: I mean, is the command line exactly the same? Did you include the quotes? Are they escaped?

Comment: Yes the command line is same as mentioned in the code space in the beginning. I tried using three quotes as well as it has space in it. It didnt work.